# Why is this map from Leray spectral sequence zero?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

In [Stacks Project Lemma 32.37.7 (0C0T)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C0T), one considers a finite morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of schemes and the Leray spectral sequence for $\mathcal O_X^*$ and $f$. It induces an edge map
$$H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_ X^*) \longrightarrow H^0(Y, R^1f_*\mathcal O_ X^*).$$
Then it claims that [Stacks Project Lemma 30.17.1 (0BUT)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BUT) shows the above edge map is zero.

The cited lemma 30.17.1 says that for any invertible $\mathcal O_X$-module $\mathcal L$ and $y\in Y$, there exists an open neighbourhood $V\subseteq Y$ of $y$ such that $\mathcal L\mid_{f^{-1}(V)}$ is trivial. I cannot perceive how this says that the above edge map is zero. I cannot even tell what the image of an invertible module under the edge map is.

---

Any help is sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you take an element in the $H^1(X, O_X^*)$ it is given by a line budle, $L$ on $X$ (up to isomorphism), such a line bundle can be restricted to $f^{-1}(V)$ and is trivial and is thus mapped to $0$ in $H^1(f^{-1}(V), O_X^*)$ and thus $L$ should be sent to $0$ as a section of $R^{1}f_*O_X^*$, given than $R^{1}f_*O_X^*(V)=H^1(f^{-1}(V), O_X^*)$

Comment: I see. Thanks for the nice explanation. I will accept it if you make the comment into an answer.

Comment: Can you use proper base change ? If yes it's immediate to see that $R^1f_* \mathcal O_X^*$ is zero.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I am not very familiar with proper base change, but I would love to know how to apply proper base change to prove this. Do we consider the base change along $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_{Y,y})\rightarrow Y$ for any $y\in Y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Tag 0BUT implies something stronger, namely that $R^{1}f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast} = 0$. One can see this as follows: Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the presheaf on $Y$ given by $V \mapsto H^{1}(f^{-1}(V),\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast})$. Then $R^{1}f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}$ is the sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$. By Tag 0BUT, for any open subset $V \subseteq Y$ and $s \in \Gamma(V,\mathcal{F})$, there is an open cover $V = \bigcup_{j \in J} V_{j}$ such that $s|_{V_{j}} = 0$ for each $j \in J$. This means that the universal separated presheaf associated to $\mathcal{F}$ is $0$, so the sheafification is $0$ as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why any $s\in\Gamma(V,\mathcal F)$ is locally trivial? You seem to be assuming that $\mathcal O_X^*$ is an invertible $\mathcal O_X$-module, which I do not know why: is it an $\mathcal O_X$-module at all?

Comment: Tag 0BUT implies that given any $y \in V$, there is an open neighborhood $V' \subset V$ of $y$ such that $s|_{V'} = 0$ in $\Gamma(V',\mathcal{F})$. Applying this to all the points of $V$ gives you the desired covering of $V$. Here I'm using that $H^{1}(f^{-1}(V),\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}) \simeq \operatorname{Pic}(f^{-1}(V))$ for any $V$. (I'm not assuming that $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}$ is an invertible $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module; indeed I don't know of a natural $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module structure on $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}$.)

Comment: OK. I misunderstood the arguments. Thanks for the explanations then. :)

Comment: @MinseonShin +1 Just a thought. Let me write $R^1_C f_\ast\mathbb{G}_m$ for the pushforward in some site (which is sensible in this context). Then, a priori the claim that $R^1_\mathrm{et}f_\ast\mathbb{G}_m=0$ (which follows immediately from the acyclicity of finite morphisms for the etale topology) is weaker than $R^1_\mathrm{Zar}f_\ast\mathbb{G}_m=0$. But, by descent for quasi-coherents they should be the same. Thoughts? I guess this is less about the OPs question (of using Tag0BUT) and more just thinking about the question directly.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Hmm I'm not sure, are you looking to generalize from $\mathbb{G}_{m}$ to some other group scheme?

Comment: @MinseonShin No, I was just trying to understand the statement in the vein of the other user's answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : I assumed that $\mathcal O^*_X$ is quasi-coherent as $\mathcal O_X$-module which is wrong. However I think the argument should still holds since proper base change and Grothendieck theorem are valid in greater generality (i.e for sheaves of abelian groups).

---

If you can use proper base change, then for any sheaf $F \in \mathcal O_X \text{-mod}$ you obtain $(R^1f_*F)_y \cong H^1(f^{-1}(y), F_{|f^{-1}(y)})$ where if $i : Z \to X$ is the inclusion of a closed subset then $F_{|Z}$ means $i^* F$. Since $f$ is finite $\dim f^{-1}(y) = 0$ and so by Grothendieck's vanishing (see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02UU)) we obtain $H^1(f^{-1}(y), F_{|f^{-1}(y)}) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the beautiful argument. :)

Comment: Dear Nicholas, I do not think that $\mathcal{O}_X^*$ is in general a quasicoherent sheaf. Consider, for instance, the scenario when $X=\Bbb A^n_{\Bbb Z}$. Can you provide an explanation of how you're considering it to be a quasicoherent sheaf?

Comment: @KReiser : I'm sorry I didn't replied to your previous comment, I agree with you $\mathcal O_X^*$ is not quasi-coherent in general. However Grothendieck vanishing theorem works for any sheaf of abelian groups and I think proper base change should holds as well.

Comment: I don't think $F$ needs to be an $\mathcal O_X$-module. As you mentioned, it only has to be an abelian sheaf. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @awllower : Yes I think abelian is enough.